# embedded https content with self-signed certificate

Tags: browser, https

Suppose I have valid HTTPS page `https://mydomain.tld` (letsencrypt certificate in this case) and I want to display images from some other domain `mystatic.tld`.

I’m aware that it is not possible to use HTTP content `http://mystatic.tld`, because browsers will block it.

What about if `mystatic.tld` is using a self-signed certificate? When opening a web page from that server, most modern browsers will give a warning and require the user the manually accept the security implications afaik. What happens to images embedded inside my original page from `mydomain.tld`?

Comment: Define what exactly you mean by "embedded"… You mean a simple `<img src="https://mystatic.tld/…">`?

Comment: Depending on the browser the resource will either be silently suppressed, or the same "trust this certificate?" message will be shown. AFAIA, the latter is more common.

Comment: @deceze: exactly like that.

Comment: Why not using a valid trusted certificate (from letsencrypt.com for example) instead of a self signed?

Comment: @Tom: Because that is not that simple for a server on a private LAN. Also I was interested in the answer to this question in general.